# Terrain analysis

Tags: python, arcgis-10.3, saga, arctoolbox

I tried running ArcSaga Morphometry python based tool for slope,aspect and curvature but it failed what could be the problem?

```
......t" # # # # # # # # # # "9 parameter 2nd order polynom (Zevenbergen & Thorne 1987)" radians radians
Start Time: Sat Nov 12 14:15:14 2016
Running script tool_0...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 74, in execute
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\ArcSAGA.py", line 90, in Run
    Result = subprocess.call(cmd, creationflags=CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Failed to execute (Slope, Aspect, Curvature).
Failed at Sat Nov 12 14:15:14 2016 (Elapsed Time: 0.02 seconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with that tool. Most of ArcSaga toolboxes works fine, but that one doesn't.

Maybe it's not my or your fault, maybe that tool just isn't write correctly?